# Can't use result of one function in other

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, filereader

I have two function

1. convertToBase64(file) for converting file
2. addData(values) for sending the converted file.
   But result in the second function is always undefined. How to fix this?

```
async function convertToBase64(file) {
  const fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = () => {
    const srcData = fileReader.result;
    console.log('scrData: ', srcData);     // result is correct
    return srcData;
  };
  fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

async function addData(values) {
  const converted = await convertToBase64(values.file);
  console.log(converted);       // result undefined
  await addDoc(collection(db, 'list'), {
    image: converted,
  });
}
```

I have tried try...catch, async-await function, but I can't find a solution anyway

Comment: You aren't returning anything from `convertToBase64`

Comment: Promisify your fileReader.on call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `convertToBase64()` function doesn't **return** a value explicitly, so the code you provided always returns `undefined`. You can change the function such that it returns a **Promise** that `resolve`s once the [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/FileReader) has done reading the file in **base64** successfully, And take care of any `reject`ions or *errors* occurs:

```js
const imgFileInput = document.getElementById("img");
imgFileInput.addEventListener("change", addData);

function convertToBase64(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = () => {
      const srcData = fileReader.result;
      resolve(srcData);
    };
    fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
      reject(error);
    };
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
}

async function addData() {
  try {
    const imgFile = imgFileInput.files[0];
    const converted = await convertToBase64(imgFile);
    console.log(converted);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error while converting to Base64:", error);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="img" />
```